# Docker : unable to load in-cluster configuration, KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT must be defined

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I just pulled one monitoring app from docker hub via Portainer on my NAS device. https://hub.docker.com/r/mercari/certificate-expiry-monitor-controller/

But when I run the container I got this error.

[ERROR] Failed to create clientSet: unable to load in-cluster configuration,

KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT must be defined

I don't have kubernates installed on my NAS, is it mandatory or how can I run it just in docker without Kubernates ?

Comment: The dockerhub page of this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mercari/certificate-expiry-monitor-controller/) mentioned that this app is used to check the expiry of TLS certificates which are used in **Ingress** services. So, obviously **kubernetes** is required to run this app as a container. **What exactly do you want to monitor on your NAS device?**

Comment: Not related to my NAS device... I used it just as test platform for running docker containers.
The Goal was to find and test some free - tiny - opensource ( SSL certificates expiration reminder  app ) which I could use it then in my work Lab to monitor ESX certificates...Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image [mercari/certificate-expiry-monitor-controller](https://hub.docker.com/r/mercari/certificate-expiry-monitor-controller/) requires **kubernetes** cluster to run because it will check the ssl certificates of the ingress resources in kubernetes.

Suggestion is you can use following images for your testing

- [dariko/docker-ssl-cert-check](https://hub.docker.com/r/dariko/docker-ssl-cert-check) by dariko
- [fuglede/certificate-expiry-alarm](https://github.com/fuglede/certificate-expiry-alarm) by fuglede

The image [**dariko/docker-ssl-cert-check**](https://hub.docker.com/r/dariko/docker-ssl-cert-check) will check the expiry of the certifications with **endpoints**. We need to mention the endpoints in a file called `/ssl_endpoints_list` which is inside of this image or you can use the `ENDPOINTS` environment variable to pass the endpoints list. It can notify the expiry through Emails by enabling the flag with an environment variable called `SEND_EMAIL`. There are other options also available like time intervals for checking the expiration. Refer to this [offical image link](https://hub.docker.com/r/dariko/docker-ssl-cert-check) for detailed information.

The image [**fuglede/certificate-expiry-alarm**](https://github.com/fuglede/certificate-expiry-alarm) will help to check the expiry of SSL certificates by a given collection of hostnames and notify the given email addresses. For the usage and other instructions refer to this [page](https://github.com/fuglede/certificate-expiry-alarm)

**NOTE: As this image fuglede/certificate-expiry-alarm is not available in dockerhub clone the git repo and build the image by making changes as per your requirements**.

Comment: Thanks for info. Looks fine... I was looking  for some web gui app with same functions ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Mostly GUI applications are paid versions, You can try with free trails if any available. If you want to know about this information in detail, I suggest you raise a new question as per stack guidelines